# Optimize graph for path finding and getting nodes at specific coordinates

Tags: python, graph, path-finding

I'm building a graph class represented as a dict. The graph class is used to perform path finding on a large 2D grid matrix. The nodes are stored as keys and the neighbour nodes are stored as values.

This works nice for fast path searches but I also need to get specific nodes out of the dict determined by their x and y coordinates.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Graph(dict):
    def get_node_at(self, x, y):
        for node in self:
            if node.x == x and node.y == y:
                return node

    def set_neighbours(self):
        pass

graph = Graph()

# build a 2d matrix of nodes
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        graph[Node(x,y)] = []

# set the neighbour nodes for each node
graph.set_neighbours()
mynode = graph.get_node_at(6,6) # will later be executed quite often
```

Is there a way to optimize the graph class so the get_node_at method performs better on a large grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an index to `Graph` which would look like `{(x,y):node}`. this would require implementing `__setitem__` to add the `Node` to the index, and remove it if another `Node` already exists and `__delitem__` would also remove the `Node` from the index. this would allow `get_node_at(self, x, y)` to just do `return self.index[(x,y)]`.

Comment: another dict inside the graph isn't pretty but should do the trick and will be much faster. thanks!